# IE11 permission denied when using domain name

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, permission-denied, documentum, webtop

We have an enterprise application using **Documentum webtop**, that we are accessing through **IE11**

When we are using one functionality by accessing the application **through IP address**, it is working fine.
But when we go **through an assigned domain name**, it is giving **permission denied** error in a JS and that functionality is not working.

[image]

Comment: what version of Webtop do you use? Is your IE browser supported for that version of webtop?

Comment: We are using Webtop 6

Comment: Saying Webtop 6 is like saying I drive BMW 5. It can be old 15 years and it can be brand new. Second part of the question? Try supported version of browser.

Comment: I agree. The thing is that we want run this app on IE 11 as our systems have upgraded to Win 8. We have resolved many compatibility  issues ourselves and this is where we are stuck.

Comment: Sounds like a cross-domain javascript security issue to me... or something very like it.

Comment: Even I think the same. Found no solutions yet.

Answer (score 2):

IE11 is not supported however your problem it's that IE11 has a brand new user-agent

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

that has not MSIE inside. Old javascript can fail because of that.

Try to force compatibility mode on browser to check if an old style user agent solve your problem.